# Can I define a variable to scale with it several figures?

Tags: subfloats, lengths, environment-variables, registers

I have several pictures in my document, using the subfigure environment, the code is the following:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pictures/...}
\end{subfigure}
```

Now, the size of the pictures will be the same for all of them. When I adjust their size, I don't want to change 0.22 to some other value for all of them. Can I define some variable? I tried with `\newlength`, but this register requires a unit of length.

Comment: Have you tried simply `\newcommand{\sizeA}{0.22}`?

Comment: @Rmano That was really simple, it works, thanks!

Comment: If you use `graphicx` then I suggest you read the package documentation because it explains how to define defaults with `\setkeys`. Also see this [presentation](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Including-Pictures.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
\newcommand{\mysize}{0.22}
```

and then

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\mysize\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pictures/...}
\end{subfigure}
```